# I can't find Emgu.CV. dll in the file

Tags: c#, file, download, missing-data, emgucv

I got a question about the file that a download.
All the tutorial said that is a file name "bin" in it but after I found it.
I only can find a "opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455_64.dll"
I can't even find "Emgu.CV.UI.dll" in this file.
The version of Emgu that I had download is 4.5.5.
Can anyone tell me where is the question?
Am I need to download the old version of Emgu or something?

Comment: where did you download your files from?

Comment: This question is rather difficult to read currently. 1. What is your actual goal? 2. What exactly have you done to reach that goal? 3. What errors do you get?